# Will a SqlConnection() declared before using it in a using() statement still close the connection when done? (C#/SQL Server)

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

In a situation like this:

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(
    ConfigurationManager
    .ConnectionStrings["AppConnection"]
    .ConnectionString
);


using (cn) {...}
```

Will the `using()` statement still close the connection even though it wasn't declared **in** the `using()` statement?

Similar to this question: [SqlConnection with a using clause - calling close on the connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135061/sqlconnection-with-a-using-clause-calling-close-on-the-connection)

Except I am wondering about using the *actual* connection, not a *copy* of it.

Comment: Yes, it will, because it calls `Dispose` at the end in a `finally`, which calls `Close`. Do take note that if `.Open()` is called before the `using`, there is a risk of leaking resources, since an exception could occur that prevents the `using` from ever being entered.

Comment: What do you mean by "Except I am wondering about using the actual connection, not a copy of it."? There is nowhere a copy used.

Comment: @Ralf Consider it a "reference to it" instead, then.  That's probably more accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but you shouldn't do it.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) for `using` says (all the way at the bottom):

> You can instantiate the resource object and then pass the variable to the using statement, but this isn't a best practice. In this case, after control leaves the using block, the object remains in scope but probably has no access to its unmanaged resources. In other words, it's not fully initialized anymore. If you try to use the object outside the using block, you risk causing an exception to be thrown. For this reason, it's better to instantiate the object in the using statement and limit its scope to the using block.
>
> ```
> var reader = new StringReader(manyLines);
> using (reader)
> {
>     ...
> }
> // reader is in scope here, but has been disposed
> ```

Comment: Normally you do this with factory methods.